# Vb.Net DataGridView Datasource Not Updating

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which is using a `DataTable` as the source (`dtOrders`) in my project. I'm trying to update `dtOrders` with an edited row and have the `DataGridView` display the updated row. I'm using the following code that is called from a `BackGroundWorker` (`bgwWriteToDatabase`)

```
Public r as ArrayList = New ArrayList

Private Sub UpdateOrderTable()

    Try
        r.Add(RowNum)
        r.Add(bwOrderID)
        r.Add(bwClientID)
        r.Add(bwMaterials)
        r.Add(bwInstaller)
        r.Add(bwMaterialsCost)
        r.Add(bwInstallerCost)
        r.Add(bwElectricalCosts)
        r.Add(bwPipeFittingCosts)
        r.Add(bwSundriesCosts)
        r.Add(bwTotalCost)
        r.Add(bwNotes)

        dtOrders.Rows(r(0))("ID") = r(1)
        dtOrders.Rows(r(0))("ClientRef") = r(2)
        dtOrders.Rows(r(0))("Materials") = r(3)
        dtOrders.Rows(r(0))("Installer") = r(4)
        dtOrders.Rows(r(0))("MaterialsCost") = r(5)
        dtOrders.Rows(r(0))("InstallersCosts") = r(6)
        dtOrders.Rows(r(0))("ElectricalWork") = r(7)
        dtOrders.Rows(r(0))("PipeFittingValves") = r(8)
        dtOrders.Rows(r(0))("Sundries") = r(9)
        dtOrders.Rows(r(0))("TotalCosts") = r(10)
        dtOrders.Rows(r(0))("Notes") = r(11)

        bgwWriteToDatabase.ReportProgress(10, 10)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message.ToString)
        Errorbits(3) = True
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub bgwWriteToDatabase_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgwWriteToDatabase.ProgressChanged
    If e.ProgressPercentage = 10 Then
        dgvViewOrders.DataSource = dtOrders
    End If
End Sub
```

The code is executed whenever the Submit button is pressed on the form. The first time the code runs, the `DataGridView` updates perfectly, it displays the new information correctly and everything seems fine.

The second time the Submit button is pressed, the information is not updated on the `DataGridView`. I'm having a hard time understanding why it works the first time, but not the second.

I have debugged and the code runs with no errors on the first run and no errors on the second run, the `BackGroundWorker` executes in the same way on both cycles but doesn't produce the update on the second time round.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I just thought... I dont clear my arraylist.. I wonder if its being added to the end

Comment: In *that* code the arraylist isnt needed.  You can add data to a DataRow without first storing vars in some other collection.  You also do not need to update a database row by row.

Comment: I pass the `r` `ArrayList` out at form close as a parameter, so I do need it in this case. I'm only updating a single row in the example above, although I could use a `with` command to make it look simpler

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add `r.Clear()` to the top of the `UpdateOrder` sub...